# Proper (or different) method of queuing dependent methods

Tags: c#, styling, code-formatting

This is question regarding proper code styling. Lets say I have couple methods that one cannot be executed if previous one was false.

How can I write it properly (or if there is no "proper" method then at least a different one) so that I don't have to build tree like this one below as such tree may grow larger and larger.

```
class Client
{
    static void Main()
    {
        if(Connect())
        {
            if(Fetch())
            {
                if(Parse())
                {
                    Print();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool Connect() { ... }

    bool Fetch() { ... }

    bool Parse() { ... }

    void Print() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Would the chain of responsibility pattern be applicale to your problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: `if (Connect() && Fetch() && Parse()) { Print(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a method that accepts a bunch of delegates:

```
public bool AllTrue(params Func<bool>[] methods) {
    foreach (var method in methods) {
        if (!method())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

..and call it like this:

```
if (AllTrue(Connect, Fetch, Parse)) {
    Print();
}
```

This is fancier than chaining logical ANDs of course.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing multiple if condition you can check all condition in single if condition

```
If (Connect() && Fetch() && Parse())
```

here, if condition first check value of Connect() method and if it's return false then it will not going to check other condition.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can use

```
static void Main()
{
    if(Connect() && Fetch() && Parse())
    {
        Print();
    }
}
```

Or

```
static void Main()
{
    if(!Connect())
        return;
    if(!Fetch())
        return;
    if(!Parse())
        return;
    Print();
}
```